# How to get Machamp in Pokemon Ash gray?

Tags: pokemon-ash-grey

I know you trade Machocke in regular games but how am I supposed to do that in the rom hack "Pokemon Ash Gray"?

Answer (score 1):

Trade evolutions in AshGray evolve through having a high happiness level instead. [Source](https://www.pokecommunity.com/showthread.php?p=7940916#post7940916)

You can increase the happiness of a Pokémon by performing certain actions like walking with it or using friendship increasing berries. You should be able to achieve a high enough friendship level through normal play. See the [Gen III mechanics](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship#In_Generation_III) for a comprehensive list of all the ways to increase friendship.